# Why does my P2FA skip every word?

Tags: phonetics, computational-linguistics

I have a .wav file and a txt file that I am trying to use with the P2FA aligner. For some reason, it skips every word. I even tried running it with just two words: "the robotics". My text file is this: THE ROBOTICS

This is the error I get:

max:desktop m$ python ./p2fa/align.py june.wav junemurphy.txt 3.TextGrid
SKIPPING WORD ??THE
SKIPPING WORD ROBOTICS
SKIPPING WORD 
SKIPPING WORD 
./tmp/sound.wav -> ./tmp/tmp.plp

I'm not sure what the question marks mean? Both of these words must be in the CMU dict.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this readme: http://www.hum.uu.nl/uilots/lab/resources/p2fa20120228.pdf

Did you remember to prepare your orthographic transcript file(the txt file)? It needs markers for pauses and start of speech.